# Get Frame src URL in address bar

Tags: html, url, frame

I'm working on making a mobile version of a website hosted on a GoDaddy Windows server.  The way GoDaddy apparently handles a mobile subdomain is by having that webpage be inside a frame.  For example:

```
 <head>

 </head>
 <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
 <frame src="myurl.com" frameborder="0" />
 <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
 </frameset>

 <!-- pageok -->
 <!-- 02 -->
 <!-- -->
 </html>
```

The problem is that any link I open in that page opens within the frame and the URL in the address bar never changes.  So my question is how can I get the frame URL to show in the browser's address bar.  As far as I know, GoDaddy doesn't give me access to the file with the above html in it to allow me to alter that.  Each page has an initial php script ran to check if it needs to redirect to a mobile browser, so if there is a way to do this with PHP, I can easily implement it.

Thanks for any help you guys can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using JavaScript on your page:

```
top.location.href = document.location.href;
```

This effectively "breaks" out of the parent frame by setting the parent frame window location to the location of the current frame.

Of course, you'd want to have some sort of indicator that you just broke out of the frame as to prevent looping:

```
if (
     (document.location.href.indexOf("#ibrokeout") == -1) &&
     (top.location != location) 
  ) {
     // Break out of the frame
     top.location.href = document.location.href + "#ibrokeout";
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried this code out now and it doesn't seem to work.  I tried throwing in an alert() to see what it was reading for the 2 locations and the problem seems to be with window.parent.location.  Do you know why it would be having issues with that?

Comment: Some more info that might help, I was looking through what the DOM object is for the page in Firebug and when I go from a link in the frame to another page, the location element under window is the previous page and I can't find anywhere in there where it is printing out the current page URL (using the firebug search feature).  The page however shows up fine within the frame.

Comment: Looks like I was able to get this done by checking the document.referrer property as this will only happen when coming from a page with the mobile subdomain in it.